# Convert tuple of tuples of floats to ints

Tags: python-3.x, int

Convert 
((2.0,3.1),(7.0,4.2),(8.9,1.0),(-8.9,7)) 
to 
((2,3),(7,4),(8,1),(-8,7))

It works to convert the tuple to a numpy array, and then apply .astype(int), but is there a more direct way? Also my 'solution' seems too special.

It works to use numpy

```
import numpy
data = ((2.0,3.1),(7.0,4.2),(8.9,1.0),(-8.9,7))
data1 = numpy.array(data)
data2 = data1.astype(int)
data3 = tuple(tuple(row) for row in data2)
data3 # ((2, 3), (7, 4), (8, 1), (-8, 7))
```

((2, 3), (7, 4), (8, 1), (-8, 7))
as expected and desired

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [16]: t = ((2.0,3.1),(7.0,4.2),(8.9,1.0),(-8.9,7))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [17]: tuple(tuple(map(int, tup)) for tup in t)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[17]: ((2, 3), (7, 4), (8, 1), (-8, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple list comprehension:

`result = [(int(element[0]), int(element[1])) for element in t]`

If you need it back as a tuple, just convert the list into a tuple:

`result = tuple([(int(element[0]), int(element[1])) for element in t])`