# Why an int is recognized as a float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, python-imaging-library

I have to create an resize algorithm in python using pillow. Some var are in french. Here, i add  to i at the end of a while (so i is always an int) and x is always an int since it's apart of the range. a[x] is a tuple.

```
from PIL import Image
photo=Image.open("meh.jpg")
from random import randint

taille=photo.size
largeur=int(taille[0]*facteur)
hauteur=int(taille[1]*facteur)
diffhauteur=hauteur-taille[1]
difflargeur=largeur-taille[0]
newImage= Image.new('RGB', (largeur,hauteur))

if diffhauteur>1:
    i=0
    while i !=taille[0]:
        a=[]
        for b in range(taille[1]):
            liste.append(photo.getpixel((i,b))) #get all the data of the pixels in the row
        for b in range(diffhauteur): #add some pixel  (gradient) to get the lenght of the new img
            index=randint(0,len(a)-2)
            pixel2=a[index+1]
            pixel1=a[index]
            ab=  degrade(pixel1,pixel2) #create a gradient of two pixels as a tuple
            a.insert(index,ab)
        for x in range (hauteur):#add the row to the new img
            newImage.putpixel((i,x),a[x])
        i=i+1

newImage.show()
```

But, i get this error:

```
#here are the values
a[x]=(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)
i=0
x=6
line 71, in resizing
    newImage.putpixel((i,x),a[x])
 
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

This does'nt happen for a specific value. It's totally random

Someone have an answer? Because it seems tricky or just too easy
I'm gonna ask to my teacher tomorrow but i don't know if i will be able to solve this.
Thanks you

Comment: What is the value of `a[x]`? Could that be a float?

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve]. We are required to guess, otherwise.

Comment: i edited the post to keep the most important piece. Sorry, i'm a beginner

Comment: Apologies, my focus was on *reproducible*. Reducing code size is nice (and will increase your chance of getting help) but removing code required to run is too much. Please try to create some code that can just run and results in the described error.

Comment: ok, i'm doing it

Comment: `int` don't have decimal places. The values in your `a[x]` have. Thus, they are not `int`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[x]` is not a tuple of `ints` as requested by the function, but a tuple of `floats`. Therefore, you have to convert this tuple to integer.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209989/convert-tuple-of-tuples-of-floats-to-ints)

You can map the tuple to integer:

```
for x in range (hauteur):
    a2 = tuple(map(int, a[x]))
    newImage.putpixel((i,x),a2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was on it since an hour. It's so silly